# EditText with dynamic ImeActionLabel

Tags: android

I have one `EditText` with dynamic action labels. For example:

```
// Checkbox selected
mEditText.setImeActionLabel("label1", R.id.action_label1);

// Checkbox unselected
mEditText.setImeActionLabel("label2", R.id.action_label2);
```

If the soft input is visible when calling `setImeActionLabel` it doesn't refresh it's state. The focus of `EditText`needs to get cleared before the action label updates properly.

Is the any kind of workarounds for this, or am I using it wrong?

Thanks.